# How do you change the Library Webpart Menu for a file?

Tags: web-part, document-library

I added a Web Part to our front page to display the most accessed library on our Team Site. But it does not give us the standard menu that is displayed in when directly in the library. Instead it open a preview window and gives limited options.

[image]

I would like to disable this and use the normal menu as the preview loads really slow and is not helpful.

I also need the regular menu to give the user the option to open the file in browser as we have it set to open in client by default and there are a few documents that they work on collaboratively in the browser mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an option, go to the change view page and choose 'Basic Table' option in the 'Style' section.

But clicking on the ellipsis in preview window would open the same menu.